# How to fix Snowflake database write error: snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 001003 (42000)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 13 unexpected 'sample'. [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE sample (\n\t"Business Address" TEXT\n)\n\n'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Have installed the necessary package: `pip install --upgrade snowflake-sqlalchemy`

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(
    'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/SAMPLE_WORK/public?warehouse=****&role=myrole'.format(user='***',password='****',account='*****') 
)

df.to_sql('sample', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SAMPLE` is a reserved keyword](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/reserved-keywords.html) in Snowflake (and SQL:2003), but it seems that the [`snowflake-sqlalchemy`](https://pypi.org/project/snowflake-sqlalchemy/) dialect does not quote it correctly. A quick hack is to inject it to the set of reserved words:

```
# Before creating the engine etc.
from snowflake.sqlalchemy.base import SnowflakeIdentifierPreparer
# The set uses lower case, though the source set upper.
SnowflakeIdentifierPreparer.reserved_words.add("sample")
```